# What signals are required for AXI-Stream Interface?

Tags: verilog, vivado-hls

For AXI stream interface which all required ?

1.ID
2.VALID
3.KEEP
4.LAST
5.READY
6.DATA
7.STRB
8.USER
9.DEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to transmit.

The minimum is valid, ready, data.

Video data often additional have:

- user[0] (for Start-Of-Frame)
- last (for End-Of-Line)

Comment: Thank you. I thought only Vaild is required ?

Comment: That is open for discussion. Without ` ready` you do not know if the data has been accepted. You could do without but then you lose the possibility of flow control. Designs get very difficult without flow control.